# Cannot Split String with String.Split('\'')

Tags: c#, string, split

I have a string which is "G:\Seriez\Futurama" I want to split it by '\'. The code below doesnt work.

```
string[] words = filePath.Split('\'');

foreach (string word in words)
{
    MessageBox.Show(word);
}
```

Comment: You should escape the backslash using another backslash.

Comment: The code you pasted is splitting the `'` instead of the slash

Comment: You could have found the answer on google faster by just pasting filePath.Split('\'') into search... Most developers do at least attempt to find the answer themselves... Just saying.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your code is not working because, while you're trying to split on the backslash,   you're not escaping correctly and are actually splitting on the single quote character.  The proper way to `Split` would be to do the following:

```
var words = filePath.Split('\\');
```

The extra slash will escape correctly, thus allowing the `Split` to correctly work on the backslash.  You can find more information on escaping characters [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h21280bw.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

Answer (score 2):

Use following code

```
  var words =filePath.Split(Path.DirectorySeparatorChar);
  foreach (string word in words)
   {
    MessageBox.Show(word);
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

you could have the string split as well using the `Literal sign` in front of your string for example

```
var somesplitString = @"G:\Seriez\Futurama";
var msgList = new List<string>();
string[] words = somesplitString.Split('\\');
foreach (string word in words)
{
   msgList.Add(word);
}
MessageBox.Show(string.Join(",", msgList));
```

`This way you can show the message box only once with all 3 values split out`